# How can I Iterate through the same dictionary multiple times in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, for-loop, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary called `categories`. And I just want to iterate through this dictionary twice in a Django template. Below is my code:

```
<div class="first">
  {% for category in categories %}
    <li class="{{category.name}}"><a href="#{{category.name}}">{{category.name}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="lenDict">
   <h2>{{categories|length}}</h2>
</div>

<div class="second">
     {% for category in categories %}
           {% for facet in allFacets %}
                 {% if category.name == facet.category %}
                    <p id="{{facet.id}}">{{facet.facet}}</p>
                 {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I do it like this the first loop under the div `first` works fine.
But when it comes to the second loop under the div `second` it gives no result.
Also the code under the div `lenDict` also gives no result.

Are there any limitations in Django templates that we cannot iterate the same dictionary twice?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this `facet.category.lower` Is it correct?

Comment: I have edited the code please have a look

Comment: I dind't ask to edit code, that was correct, my concern was is category is a field in facet?  What is `{{facet.facet}}` ?

Comment: you need to show your view code here.

Comment: {{facet.facet}} gives a facet name. This code is working fine. The thing is that if i am using only one of these for loop its working fine. If i am using these dictionary categories at two times the second one will not give any result.

Comment: Which version of django are you using.  Can iterate through a list twice in 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through an entire `dict` in Python, you should use [`.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems). It creates a new iterator over the `(key, value)` pairs of the dict. You could also use [`items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) if you wanted a `list` of items instead.

```
<div class="first">
  {% for key, value in categories.iteritems() %}
    <li class="{{ key }}"><a href="#{{ key }}">{{ value }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="lenDict">
   <h2>{{ categories|length }}</h2>
</div>

<div class="second">
     {% for key, value in categories.iteritems() %}
           {% for facet in allFacets %}
                 {% if key == facet.category %}
                    <p id="{{facet.id}}">{{facet.facet}}</p>
                 {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note that your dict will be unordered. If you want to preserve the orders of the keys, use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 0):

So I think this works. I think your issue is facet.category. Is this a fk? because if this is a fk the if statement should be

```
{% if category.id == facet.category %}
```

In python iterators don't need to be reset, so I don't think you have to reset your iterators in the tamplate. 
Note: I would leave this is in a comment but rep isn't high enough.